# Multer upload multiple files from different inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer

I'm rather new to multer/node/express/mongoose/... and I'm currently trying to upload multiple files from different inputs that have the same name (I generate the inputs using reactjs).

Here's my React front-end:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    const {imges} = this.state;
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('imges', imges);

    axios.post('newuser',
        formData)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

handleFileChange(inputid, file) {
    const data = [...this.state.data];
    this.setState({
        imges: this.state.imges.concat(file)
    }, () => console.log(this.state.imges));
}

render() {
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
            <Imageinput onhandleChange={this.handleFileChange}/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

I didn't add in how I generate the fields because I felt that it wasn't relevant to the question, however, I would like to note that the user can generate however many of these file-inputs with the name-attribute "picture" as he wants.

Here's my node.js backend:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./uploads/");
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const newFilename = `${uuidv4()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null, newFilename);
    },
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
router.post("/", upload.array("picture"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files + " and exit");
    res.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

I also tried using `upload.any()` but it didn't work and I also read that there can be security hazards with using that. I'm a little confused here, all questions/answers I've seen up until now simply use `req.files` and they receive an array of their files or at least something, but for me the terminal simply prints out `and exit` so I'm assuming there is a mistake within my code.
I also tried setting "picture[]" as the name of my inputs, since, in php that indicated an array of files (I know php is not node.js, but I wanted to try out as much as possible before asking here).

To sum up my question: I would like to retrieve the filedata from my files from different inputs, which have the same name, using multer. It is not working, therefore I would like to ask if anyone knows what I did wrong in this case and how I can fix it.

(Edit: This is probably a little of topic but it seems to me that this question is too "small" to be asked as its own question. In my form I also have a few text inputs. Before using multer I stored the data gathered from each of my components (`Imageinput`) in its own array in the state like so:

```
 data : [{data1: value, imgsrc: value}, {data1: value, imgsrc: value}, ... ]
```

Can send the images as a part of this array using multer?
).

Answer (score 2):

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './client/uploads/')
    },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1]) //Appending extension
    }
});

const Upload = multer({storage: storage}).any();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    Upload(req, res, function (err, filedata) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});

        } else {
            functionName(req.files, function (result) {
                            res.json(result);
            })
        }
       })
});
```

Comment: Could you go into more detail regarding what you did exactly?

Comment: step-1: Assigning the destination folder where the files should be saved.Step-2:filename:creating a unique filename using Date.Step-3:any() is used for uploading multiple file at a time.Step-4:through router input the files.

Comment: I have a few more questions. Why do I have to assign the files a unique filename the way you did, because I did that in my code as well. Why do you append `any()` in your `Upload` variable and not in `router.post()` as `Upload.any()` ?

Comment: In addition I would like to ask where you got `functionName` from. What function is that referring to?

Comment: In case if you want a single file from thousands of files.It will be easy to retrieve. any() is used for uploading multiple files, if you don't use any() then only one file can be uploaded at a time.To avoid complexity of the code i have used in this way.

Comment: functionName defines that to which function you want to pass the file.Based on your requirement use the functionName if needed

Comment: I see, thank you very much. It still does not save the files to my folder. Instead of functionName in the else-statement, I simply did `console.log(req.files)` but it returned an empty array. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: I'm saving all of the file values in a state-array, could that be the issue?

Comment: [ { fieldname: 'image',
    originalname: 'Yellow.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: './client/uploads/',
    filename: '1516345156498.jpg',
    path: 'client/uploads/1516345156498.jpg',
    size: 6231 } ]

Comment: no unfortunately not, it simply returned an empty array

Comment: try to use console.log(req).Observer what you got in the request

Comment: In your schema give the field value as [String].Then it will save the filename.That is for example image:[String]

Comment: but I have several files, shouldn't it be an array in that case?

Comment: so, just to make sure, even though it's an array I should use `imges: String` in my schema? I tried that and now it just didn't add a value for imges in my db

Comment: use imges:[String]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163481/discussion-between-udaykumar-vangari-and-a-s-j).