# I want to pass 2 images array from my angular frontend to my backend node js

Tags: node.js, angular

This is my backend code where i get my frontend data

````
router.post( "",multer({ storage: storage }).array(
 'image[]',6,
 'freeimagePath[]', 8 
  ) ,
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("image is ",req.body.image);
    console.log("freeimage is ",req.body.freeimage);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forms `multipart/form-data` in order to send such images. So it can select multiple images or using multiple inputs.

You can check this article: [Implementing File Upload Using Node and Angular](https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-file-upload-using-node-and-angular/)

Comment: Yes i am already using multer please find the below ```const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
  //  console.log("file name is",file );
    let error = new Error("Invalid mime type");
    if (isValid) {
      error = null;
    }
    cb(error, "api/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const name = file.originalname
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ")
      .join("-");
    const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    cb(null, name + "-" + Date.now() + "." + ext);
 
  }
});

Comment: To be more clear i am sending two array images (images,freeimages) to backend (nodejs) but in node js i can only retrieve one array by the followingrouter.post( "",multer({ storage: storage }).array(
 'image[]',6
  ) ,
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("image is ",req.body.image);
}``` how can i retrieve both the arrays is my question. can you help me on this

Comment: So you will need to work with `upload.any()` instead of `upload.array()`. This reference may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337599/multer-upload-multiple-files-from-different-inputs